# Icon launches python script but doesn't save .txt

Tags: python

I created a simple program using tkinter. Whether I run it by clicking on piriquita.py or through terminal, the data log_piriquita.tx is created if it doesn't exist or it is appended if it already exists. Fact is: a .txt file is created and saves data alright.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#17.10.2019 terminado 18.10.2019
#programa para cálculos da Piriquita


from tkinter import*
from datetime import date

janela = Tk(className='piriquita')

def calcular():
    print("calcular")

d = float(dose.get())
p = float(peso.get())
c = float(conc.get())

v = d*p/c

lbl_resultado['text'] = round(v, 1)

data_atual = date.today()
data_normal = data_atual.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

f = open('log_piriquita.txt', 'a+')
f.write(f'{data_normal}: Dose {d}, peso {p}, conc {c} = {v:.1f}\n')
f.close()

lbl_dose = Label(janela, text='Dose (mg)', font=(None, 15))
lbl_dose.place(x=10, y= 20)
dose = Entry(janela, width="6", font=(None, 15))
dose.place(x=130, y=20)

lbl_peso = Label(janela, text='Peso (kg)', font=(None, 15))
lbl_peso.place(x=10, y= 60)
peso = Entry(janela, width="6", font=(None, 15))
peso.place(x=130, y=60)

lbl_conc = Label(janela, text='Conc.(mg)', font=(None, 15))
lbl_conc.place(x=10, y= 100)
conc = Entry(janela, width="6", font=(None, 15))
conc.place(x=130, y=100)

bt = Button(janela, text="Calcular", width=5, command = calcular,
font=(None, 15), fg='purple') 
bt.place(x=80, y=140)

lbl_resul = Label(janela, text="Resultado", fg="red", font=(None, 22))
lbl_resul.place(x=10, y=200)
lbl_resultado = Label(janela, text="0", fg="red", font=(None, 22, 
'bold'))
lbl_resultado.place(x=190, y=200)

janela.geometry("300x250+300+300")

janela.title("Piriquita")

janela.mainloop()
```

Then I created an executable icon.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=Piriquita
Exec=/home/js/Coding/Atom/Piriquita/piriquita.py
Icon=/home/js/Coding/Atom/Piriquita/piriquita1.png
StartupWMClass=piriquita
```

All fine. It works ok but doesn't create the log_piriquita.txt as the script piriquita.py does. What am I missing, please.

I use Mint 19. Python 3.6

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the current directory when the script runs? This is where the file should appear (possibly your home directory). You should give an absolute path when opening the file in the code, or use a [`Path` directive](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#recognized-keys) in your .desktop to set the working directory of the application when it runs.

Comment: It appeared in my home directory!  Thanks a lot!